# how to call url in yii2 when capital table name

Tags: database, url, yii2

In database have capital database name. 
example. `ACCOUNT`

then gii model , CRUD 
and then call url `domain.com/web/index.php?r=ACCOUNT`

but it's error `Not Found (#404)`

I try `domain.com/web/index.php?r=Account` or `domain.com/web/index.php?r=account`

It also error  `Not Found (#404)`

how to call url in yii2 when capital table name

Comment: What does database name have to do with URLs?

Comment: in the same database i have lowercase table name example `user`
I can call `domain.com/web/index.php?r=user`. It's not error.

I guess this problem because capital database name.

Comment: I'm afraid you have no idea how Yii 2 works. Read more about [routing](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html) first.

Comment: check the real name you have in related controller ..